# How do I define colors in imagesc based on the values of the data

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

I am trying to change the color scale on imagesc plot, according to the value of my data.

My data is a vector, with values ranging from 0-50.

I have setup my colormap like this:

```
color = [0  0   0
         linspace(.7,1,6)' linspace(.5,1,6)' linspace(0,0,6)'];
```

I have also set up a vector that assigns a different index to each of the values from the data.

```
for i=1:length(mydata)

  if (mydata(i)==0)
      index(i)=1;
  elseif(mydata(i)==1)
      index(i)=2;
  elseif(mydata(i)==2)
      index(i)=2;    
  elseif(mydata(i)==3)
      index(i)=3;
  elseif(mydata(i)==4)
      index(i)=3;
  elseif(mydata(i)>5 & mydata(i)<10)
      index(i)=4;
  elseif(mydata(i)>10 & mydata(i)<15)
      index(i)=5;
  elseif(mydata(i)>15 & mydata(i)<20)
      index(i)=6;
  else
      index(i)=7;

  end
end
```

But, how do I pass it now to the imagesc function?

Any other suggestion on how to solve this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change `length(mydata)` to `numel(mydata)` in your loop. Otherwise you are not accessing all elements of `mydata`. Or better, do it vectorized (without loops):

```
index = NaN(size(mydata)); %// preallocate
index(mydata==0) = 1;
index(mydata==1) = 2;
%// etc.
```

Then just use

```
imagesc(index); %// display image
colormap(color); %// set your matrix "color" as the colormap
colorbar %// show color bar, if desired
```

Comment: imagesc(index)!
Yes! I just realized that myself! Thanks a lot!!